# An error ocurred when executing GradeBook

Tags: java

```
public class test{
    public void mosleh(String coursName)
    {
        System.out.printf("Welocm to grade bok for\n%s!\n,coursName");
    }
}
```

--

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBookTest {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        GradeBook  myGradeBook = new GradeBook ();
        System.out.println("please enter the cours name");
        String nameOfCourse = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        myGradeBook.mosleh(nameOfCourse);
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: post the stacktrace and the question.. Without seeing an error we just can guess.

Comment: add more details to get anwer

Answer (score 3):

Its unclear what youre asking but you need to rename your `test` class to avail of the `mosleh` method

```
public class GradeBook {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `mosleh()` method as static

```
public static void mosleh(String coursName);
```

In order to use it in this way:

```
myGradeBook.mosleh(nameOfCourse);
```

Or create an object from `myGradeBook` then call the method, like this:

```
new myGradeBook().mosleh(nameOfCource);
```

Consider that you need to change the class name to `myGradeBook` instead of `test`

Comment: please acept it as answer if its solved your problem